# Executing shell scripts within another shell script through Java code

Tags: java, bash, shell, processbuilder

In my Spring-boot application, I am trying to trigger a shell script which in turns internally executes several other shell scripts.I am able to trigger my main script (say master.sh) using ProcessBuilder, but thereon any scripts being called within master.sh do not run. In fact, nothing happens.

At a high-level, I am trying to do the following in my master.sh -

- Check for some condition
- Execute another shell script              This never executes hence no further statements execute.
- make curl call back to my spring-boot app
  .....

Any help please...

Comment: Does your master.sh script work when you call it manually? Does it depend on some variables in the environment being set (e.g. PATH)? Does it need to run as a specific user?

Comment: Yes, it works completely fine on command line (bash). I tried - with a waitFor call in Java code and redirected error/output streams to find out errors - the master.sh actually triggered internal scripts and made"curl" callback to my application. My requirement - user triggers master.sh via UI - internal scripts runs could take between 30mins-3+ hrs to complete. With waitFor call in Java code, UI remains  blocked and prevents user to continue. Anything that I can try out in the shell script that could ensure the internal script execution ? Any pointers please ?

Comment: @Henry : Does it need to run as a specific user? - no this is not the case.

Comment: This sounds now like the callback is actually working (so nothing wrong with the script) but somehow your Java process gets locked up.

Comment: Callback via curl always work (both while manually executing the script or triggering via the Java code), but in my script (master.sh) I have multiple calls to other .sh scripts and those are the ones that do not work. Triggering master.sh via code (without waitFor call) does nothing and the next statement in the script does not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick recap of the use case I was struggling with - In my spring-boot app, user has an option to trigger a main script (say master.sh) - this main script internally does the below -

(a). Executes another script present at some other location on the system :: this script could take anywhere between 30 mins - 3+ hours to execute.

(b). Once step (a) completes, master.sh (main script) runs curl commands to make a callback to my Spring boot application in order to perform updates to the DB.

Above steps a & b are executed multiple times inside the master.sh

**Solution** : As for triggering any command from Java code, i used ProcessBuilder to achieve the same. But I had to add below additional statements before issuing processBuilder.start() call in order to make it work -

```
processBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

Above statements redirect the script output to the parent process's (in this case Java) error and output streams.

At the moment it has worked for me. In case the behavior changes (which I don't anticipate) then I will update this thread accordingly.

Lastly, I would request others to share their understanding on why without the above two statements my internal scripts did not run. I do understand the "why" but not finding a clear wording to explain. Thanks All.